# UpdateModel in MVC creates duplicate/orphaned records of child list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I'm using MVC 5 with Entity Framework Code First.

I have a Class (school class) object that has a List of Students attached to it and I'm attempting to update the class and/or students within the class and what I get when I call `SaveChanges()` on the context are duplicate records for the students in the class. Basically the old student list gets "orphaned" in the database and a whole new set of students is attached to the edited class in the database.

So instead of 10 corrected student records in the database, I now have 20 student records. The 10 original (uncorrected) and 10 new (corrected) ones. The 10 original ones have the `classid` foreign key removed so they are no longer part of that class.

Any updates to the Class object are implemented fine without duplicating the Class record.

I've seen one answer that suggests that maybe the context doesn't know that the students are not new items so it adds them... and to grab the students from the database so the context knows about them - but if the students come along when you pull the class object from the database, isn't that the same thing as pulling the directly?

```
  public class Class
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid ClassId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Class Name")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        ClassId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }

   }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, FormCollection collection)
    {                   
        Class selectedclass = db.Classes.Find(id);

        try
        {                                                
            UpdateModel(selectedclass, collection.ToValueProvider());
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(selectedclass);
        }
    }
```

What in the world am I doing wrong?

The only thing that I can think of to do is to remove all the student records that are attached to that class in the database before I save the changes, but there has to be a better way than that.

```
db.Students.RemoveRange(db.Classes.Find(id).Students);
```

So I tried attaching the students in the list to the context and even changing their state to modified, like:

```
 selectedclass.Students.ForEach(s => db.Students.Attach(s));
 selectedclass.Students.ForEach(s => db.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Modified);
```

But no luck, still getting duplicates and orphans.

Tried getting the students directly from the database, but no luck:

```
 var ids = selectedclass.Students.Select(s => s.StudentId).ToList();           

 selectedclass.Students = db.Students.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.StudentId)).ToList()
```

HTML for the editor for the student:

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count; i++)
  {
      <div class="col-md-8">
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Students[i], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
      </div>
  }
```

The editor template for student:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
</div>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect the values of `selectedclass` before and after your use of `UpdateModel()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke They change from what they were to what I want them to update to... no issue there. Its just that the new list gets added to the database like its a brand new list instead of updating the existing list of students.

Comment: But you noted in your question that the ClassId property is removed?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - bad explanation on my part... the property that is cleared is on the student object that effectively removes the student from the class. It is done on the existing students in the database, not the ones in the list attached to the class I'm working with.

Comment: The problem may lie with your database code - but you give no details there.  One could assume entity framework, and then you might be running into detached entity issues, but since you give no details, it's just a wild guess.

Comment: @Nathan - I added EF tags...

Comment: What does your `UpdateModel` method look like?

Comment: @Nathan - its not MY UpdateModel method... its from the Controller class that is in System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: @BarryFranklin - Oh right.  I almost never use UpdateModel directly - I prefer to just take a strongly typed *view* model class as an argument to my post action.  I almost never take a raw FormCollection.  I now see that you are using your mapped entity framework class and directly updating to it.  This is a dangerous thing to do, it can open you up to overposting vulnerabilities.  See http://www.codethinked.com/aspnet-mvc-think-before-you-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that you are loading the entity with `Class selectedclass = db.Classes.Find(id);`, but that does *not* automatically load the collection of students.

I suspect that what is happening is that since the `Students` collection is not loaded, most likely `UpdateModel` simply calls the `Students` setter, which *replaces* the collection.

Since the `Student` objects were not loaded by the context, Entity Framework thinks they are new students, and inserts them accordingly. See [Data Points - Why Does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

There are a couple solutions to this.  You can try explicitly loading the Students collections before calling `UpdateModel`.  Or you can explicitly tell entity framework that the student records are existing, by explicitly attaching them to the context.

However, in general, I try to avoid dealing with disconnected entities - there are lots of "gotchas" in Entity Framework disconnected entity handling.

Also, be careful when binding directly to your Entity Framework mapped classes, as this can easily lead to overposting/underposting security vulnerabilities. See [ASP.NET MVC – Think Before You Bind](http://www.codethinked.com/aspnet-mvc-think-before-you-bind)

**Update**
I'm beginning to suspect that the issue lies with how the html is specifying the form fields.  See [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Your other option of course, is to *not* use `UpdateModel` in this fashion.  Instead, just load the entity and "manually" apply the edits to the loaded entity.  From a security perspective, this is less likely to cause issues.  In which case, I'd probably recommend moving to strongly typed views so that you don't have to hunt through the form collection with dictionary keys.

Comment: When I step through the code, the Students on selectedClass are there once selectedClass is loaded. I've tried explicitly loading the students - didn't seem to work. Attached them, changed their state - didn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled?  If so, simply watching the variable in the debugger could potentially trigger lazy loading to occur, so that what you see in debugging isn't necessarily what happens when you run outside of debugging - kind of depends on the exact inner workings of UpdateModel.  Though since you also explicitly loaded the students collection, I'm beginning to think the problem lies in your html not rendering the id fields according to the default model binder convention.

Comment: @BarryFranklin - I don't see any place in your editor template that you actually render `StudentId`.  It would at least need to be present as a hidden field, e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentId)`

Comment: That may be part of the issue... I did that and then I also stopped using the update model method and just updated the data and called SaveChanges() on the context and it is working fine now - the data gets updated and I get no duplicates or orphans. Thanks.